# AWS Lambda Can Read But Not Write To RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, geopandas

I'm currently writing an AWS Lambda that will write to an RDS Database. I'm able to read from the database, but the connection times out when attempting to write to the database. I'm wondering if it is because I'm trying to write a geopandas DF to the Postgres database from within the aws lambda as so:

```
eng = create_engine('postgresql://' + 'postgres_db' + \
                                ':' + 'password' + \
                                '@' + 'host_loc' + \
                                ':' + 'port' + \
                                '/' + 'db_name')
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .

df1.to_postgis('table1', con=eng, if_exists='replace', index=False)
df2.to_postgis('table2', con=eng, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

But the script keeps failing with:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}
```

Would the to_postgis function of geopandas possibly be causing this and how would I be able to correct this? I know I'm able to read from the DB as I've tested that successfully from the lambda environment. The script only fails when trying to use to_postgis to write the geopandas dataframes to postgis in my postgres instance.

Comment: Could it be that this write operation takes more than 3 seconds so you need to increase the Lambda function's timeout setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default timeout for AWS Lambda functions is 3 seconds. The timeout is designed to stop "runaway" tasks, since most Lambda functions only run for a fraction of a second.

You can increase this up to a maximum of 15 minutes. The configuration can be found on the page when you open the function.

It is likely that the database write operation is taking too long, causing the Lambda function to timeout. Giving it more time is likely to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly it! I'm not too familiar with AWS Lambda so thank you so much for your help and patience!